# Preconditioning ARPACK eigenvalue solver

Tags: linear-algebra, eigensystem, arpack

I am working on a generalized eigenvalue problem of the form

$$
\boldsymbol{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}=\lambda\boldsymbol{B}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}
$$

where $\boldsymbol{B}$ is **not** symmetric positive. Therefore I recast the problem to
$$
\boldsymbol{B}^{-1}\cdot(\boldsymbol{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{x})=\lambda\boldsymbol{x}\ .
$$
I am *lucky*: the matrix $\boldsymbol{B}$ is block diagonal. Therefore I can compute the inverse by an LU-factorization of the diagonal blocks.

This eigenvalue problem is then solved with the ARPACK solver. ARPACK is used because of its feature to extract specific parts of the spectrum like eigenvalues with the largest real part. The method works well for small problems.

However, if I increase the problem size, the performance of the ARPACK algorithmen in terms of iterations required increases. The condition number of $\boldsymbol{B}^{-1}\cdot\boldsymbol{A}$ increases heavily up to the order $10^6$.

Is there a way of preconditioning the ARPACK algorithmen to accelerate the convergence?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are looking only for the largest eigenvalues? How many iteration vectors (ncv) are you using? You might try increasing this number to see how that affects the computation cost. I suggest you provide the details on exactly how you are using arpack.

Comment: @BillGreene I am not always looking for the same part of the spectrum. Sometimes I need the say 12 eigenvalues with largest real part, sometimes the 12 eigenvalues of smallest magnitude. I am not specifying `ncv` at all. But I will try. I am using arpack through `scipy`. My call looks like this `l, v = scipy.sparse.linalg(LinOp, k = 12, which = "SM", tol = 1e-12, maxiter = 200)

Comment: That complicates things considerably. I don't know the scipy interface to arpack. Does your LinOp simply multiply a vector with a matrix? If so, the convergence of the smallest eigenvalues can be very slow. As I suggested previously, you can try making ncv much larger. The only efficient way to calculate the smallest eigenvalues is to essentially "invert" A.

Comment: @sebastian_g How are you implementing your LinOp applied to a vector $v$? It it something along the lines of (1) $ z \leftarrow A v$ (2) Solve $M w = z$ (for $w$, using the pre-computed factorization of $M$).

Comment: @sebastian_g Also - where are your matrices $A$ and $M$ coming from? Do they have any sort of special structure? Do you have a reasonable idea about the magnitude of your eigenvalues (is shift-invert an option?)

Comment: @GoHokies The linear operator works as you described. I am using a precomputed sparse block LU factorization.
Actually for my *test case* the matrices posses a special structure. $A$ and $B$ are block diagonal. I know the eigenvalues exactly from my analytic solution. Further I know that the there is multiple eigenvalues.
For my *real application* $B$ is still block diagonal, but $A$ is not. Both matrices results from a finite difference discretization. Further $A$ depends on a parameter which influence shall be considered.

Comment: @BillGreene Indeed you are right the parameter `ncv` has a positive effect. A solve for the eigenvalues of largest magnitude is faster than for smallest magnitude. Thank You for your advice.

Comment: @sebastian_g ARPACK is less adept at finding the smallest eigenvalues. You could use the [shift-invert approach](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/arpack.html#shift-invert-mode) to speed things up if you know where your target eigenvalues are situated (e.g. if they are close to a certain real value, then that value is a good candidate for the shift $\sigma$).

Comment: @GoHokies Thank you for your comment. Is the shift-invert approach also suitable with $\sigma=0$? I think that is the best guess for my problem. 

Do you have experience regarding Krylov-Schur methods? If I understood the SLEPc documentation right, these methods also allow to search for certain parts of the spectrum. I could incorporate PETSc and SLEPc using their python wrappers. But that would be a lot of effort...

Comment: Sebastian, 
for shift-reduce small eigenvalues did you run `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs( ... sigma=0, which="LM" )` ?
I at first missed "When sigma is specified, 'which' refers to the *shifted* eigenvalues."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've summarized the comments thread of your original question into an answer.

Here are a few things that you can try:

1. Increase the number of your Arnoldi vectors (**NCV**) generated at each iteration. Here's what the ARPACK documentation for [DSAUPD](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node136.html) says about this:

   `At present there is no a-priori analysis to guide the selection of NCV relative to NEV (the number of eigenvalues you're looking for). The only formal requirement is that NCV > NEV. However, it is recommended that NCV >= 2*NEV.`

   `If many problems of the same type are to be solved, one should experiment with increasing NCV while keeping NEV fixed for a given test problem. This will usually decrease the required number of OP*x operations but it also increases the work and storage required to maintain the orthogonal basis vectors. The optimal "cross-over" with respect to CPU time is problem dependent and must be determined empirically.`
2. Revisit your implementation of the linear operator. In your case, it should read something like:

   (a) $ z \leftarrow A v$

   (b) Solve $M w = z$ for $w$, using the pre-computed factorization of $M$.
3. If you're looking for the smallest eigenvalues - or eigenvalues close to a given real value, it is advisable to use the [shift-and-invert mode of ARPACK](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/arpack.html#shift-invert-mode). The shift $\sigma$ can be zero (see the example they give [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/arpack.html#shift-invert-mode)) or any other real/complex value. Your linear operator becomes $(A - \sigma M)^{-1} M $ (for $M$ symmetric and indefinite).
4. If SciPy-ARPACK works well enough for your problem, then PETSc/SLEPc are probably overkill.